# Add custom header in request.servervariables()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to add HTTP_MSDN in header so that whenever I will click on button this HTTP_MSDN should be visible for this url. Please help me.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
    //HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://wap.mobiletashan.com") as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    request.Headers.Add("HTTP_MSDN", "0123456789");                      
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameValueCollection coll;
    coll = Request.ServerVariables;
    String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys;
    String[] arr2 = coll.GetValues(arr1[0]);
    Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[0]));
}
```

Comment: I want when I click on button whatever header I have added it should be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add your header to request, add it before getting response, like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
request.Headers.Add("HTTP_MSDN", "0123456789"); 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I have add it but When I click on button HTTP_MSDN header is not showing. Please share update...

Comment: Some misunderstanding... Do you want to add your header to you page when clickin on button?

Comment: I want to add this header request.Headers.Add("HTTP_MSDN", "0123456789") dueing page load. Also I want get this header along with all headers get by request.servervariables("ALL_HTTP") on button click